Why does `std::integral_constant` have a `::type` that refers to itself?
I'm reading the documentation on std::integral_constant, and apparently it includes using type that refers to itself.
template <typename T, T Value>
struct integral_constant
{
    using type = integral_constant<T, Value>;
    // ...
};

What is this typedef used for?
To access it you already need to know the type, so I don't see what benefit it brings.

Because these are often used as base classes.

It's to facilitate other code that needs to use it's type.  Collaborative coding.

From N1424:

An important use case for providing a type representation for the result of Boolean traits comes from the template metaprogramming, the discipline where class templates are treated as compile-time invocable entities (metafunctions), and where experience has shown that to build a consistent and coherent framework of well-interpolating components it's crucially important for the metafunctions to provide a single common form of invocation [11]. Since it is possible to wrap an integral constant in a type, but not vice-versa, the implementation of boost type traits library was re-written to provide the result of Boolean trait templates through both their static const bool value member and the nested type typedef exposing the corresponding specialization of an integral constant type wrapper.

So if you had some overloaded function like:
void do_something(std::true_type);
void do_something(std::false_type);

For any "Boolean trait", you can always use do_something(typename Trait<T>::type{}).
This is especially useful when Trait is built up from other template metaprogramming, which might only give a type member but not a value (because it was meant for types), e.g.:
template<typename Trait, typename T>
void call_do_something() {
    do_something(typename Trait<T>::type{});
}

int main() {
    using namespace mp = ::metaprogramming_library;
    using is_single_dim_array = mp::partial<mp::ic_equal, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1>, std::rank>;
    // partial only has a member type because it's meant for type tratis
    call_do_something<is_single_dim_array::type, int[1]>();
    call_do_something<is_single_dim_array::type, int[1][2]>();
}


The quote from N1424 is not convincing - it just says it is done like that because it could be done. More than that, in the following example with copy and do_copy a convertability of trait's instantiated template is utilized, and its ::type member type is never used. One convincing example I could think of is using trait's result to instantiate a class template which is specialized with one of std::true_type or std::false_type, and not some type that is derived from them.

The example provided in the answer is not clear - why do_something can't accept typename Trait<T>{}? Is it because newly created by mp::partial trait cannot be converted to std::true_type or std::false_type? If yes then it violates the implicitly convertible to X::type property of instantiated traits that is in the cited C1424.

"Whether this is accomplished by inheritance or by a member operator is unspecified.": Theoretically a trait could do using type = ...; operator type() const { return type(); }, so trait::value wouldn't work. But I guess then Trait<T>{} would work and typename Trait<T>::type{} wouldn't be needed. Trait<T>::type::value would be needed to get the underlying value though if it chooses to use a conversion function instead of a base class


To access it you already need to know the type, so I don't see what benefit it brings. What is this typedef used for?

This can be answered from meta.help that says:

The class template integral_constant, alias template bool_constant, and its associated typedef-names true_type and false_type are used as base classes to define the interface for various type traits.

